# Turn list with dates into data frame in R

Tags: r, list, date, dataframe

I have troubles with converting a `list` containing dates into a `date.frame`, as the dates are converted into integers when using the `unlist` command.

The `list` I work on looks similar to this, just with way more data frames:

```
list(
    data.frame(
        date = as.POSIXct(Sys.time() + days(seq(0, 4))),
        value = c(4,5,1,7,9)),
    data.frame(
        date = as.POSIXct(Sys.time() + days(seq(5, 9))),
        value = c(3,3,5,1,7))
)
```

What I am looking for a method to convert it into a single `data.frame` that look like this:

```
                  date   value
1  2017-07-24 14:30:18       4
2  2017-07-25 14:30:18       5
3  2017-07-26 14:30:18       1
4  2017-07-27 14:30:18       7
5  2017-07-28 14:30:18       9
6  2017-07-29 14:30:18       3
7  2017-07-30 14:30:18       3
8  2017-07-31 14:30:18       5
9  2017-08-01 14:30:18       1
10 2017-08-02 14:30:18       7
```

Comment: you can use do.call(rbind,x) where x is your list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst)
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst)
```